# webview doesn't show up underneath button in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

Before I implemented a linear layout with button and webview, my standalone webview worked fine.  I added the following and now only the button shows up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_nav"
     />

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I just want a button that spans the top, with a webview underneath it that fills the rest of the view.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your orientation is set to horizontal, and the button is set to "fill_parent", so that means the webview will come to the right of the button, which fills the entire screen, making the webview appear off the screen.

To fix this, set orientation of your LinearLayout to "vertical".